# How to make a reader app where text should adjust in multiple pages according to screen size and font size

Tags: android

How to make UI for a book reader in Android, with horizontal page flip. Text should adjust in multiple pages according to screen size and font size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make multiple values folders like this in the image
than in every dimens.xml provide specific values according to you needs.Like i have given

in values-hdpi/dimens.xml

```
  <dimen name="titlebar_NexttextSize">17.0sp</dimen>
```

in values-ldpi/dimens.xml

```
  <dimen name="titlebar_NexttextSize">13.0sp</dimen>
```

in values-mdpi/dimens.xml

```
  <dimen name="titlebar_NexttextSize">15.0sp</dimen>
```

in values-xlarge/dimens.xml

```
  <dimen name="titlebar_NexttextSize">19.0sp</dimen>
```

Now in your layout.xml file use

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Car"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"                
            android:textSize="@dimen/titlebar_capital_textSize" />" />
```

This will assign the sizes as per your screen size.

[image]